# How to find direction of the negative gradient vector?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, backpropagation

I'm a ninth grader who's working on a Neural Network that takes 28x28 grid pixels(from mnist) and guesses a number.

At the backpropagation, there's something I don't understand. You count the partial derivatives of the cost function with respect to the partial derivatives of the weights and the biases. Then, you put them in a direction vector, where you count the nudges you need to add to the weights and make an average of those over 10000 pictures. And here's the problem: How do you count those little nudges from the partial derivatives of the cost function with respect to the partial derivatives of the weights and the biases to find the minimum of the cost?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTQcn.jpg)

Comment: Basically the gradient of the cost function is computed using the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: okay i understand it but how?